# How would I search for a user determined word and count the occurrences in a text file using java?

Tags: java

I've gotten to a point where I can read the file and output the actual text in the file but i'm not quite sure on how to proceed with searching for a specific word and displaying the word count.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways.  If you're reading the file line-by-line, you can using the method `indexOf` on the `String` class to search each line for the text.  You'd need to call it repeatedly to move through the line looking for additional occurrences.

See documentation on `indexOf` at:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String,%20int)

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question, if you are reading the text line after line you can use recursivity to count how many occurences of the word appear in the same line:

The following method counts how many times a word appears in the same line

```
private static int numberOfLineOccurences;

public static int countNumberOfTimesInALine(String line, String word) {
    if (line.indexOf(word) == -1) {
        return numberOfLineOccurences;
    } else {
        numberOfLineOccurences++;
        if (line.indexOf(word) + word.length() >  line.length() -1     ) {
            return numberOfLineOccurences;
        }
        return countNumberOfTimesInALine(
                line.substring(line.indexOf(word) + word.length()), word );
    }

}
```

In order to keep track of the first occurence of my word in my file along with the number of occurence I created a WordInfo class like this:

```
class WordInfo {

    private int firstOccurenceLineNumber;
    private int firstOccurenceColumnNumber;
    private String word;
    private int numberOfOccurences;

    public String getWord() {
        return word;
    }

    public int getNumberOfOccurences() {
        return numberOfOccurences;
    }

    public WordInfo(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }

    public void upOccurrence() {
        numberOfOccurences++;
    }

   public void upOccurrence(int numberOfTimes) {
        numberOfOccurences+= numberOfTimes;
    }

   public int getFirstOccurenceLineNumber() {
    return firstOccurenceLineNumber;
    }

   public void setFirstOccurenceLineNumber(int firstOccurenceLineNumber) {
       this.firstOccurenceLineNumber = firstOccurenceLineNumber;
    }

   public int getFirstOccurenceColumnNumber() {
       return firstOccurenceColumnNumber;
    }

    public void setFirstOccurenceColumnNumber(int     firstOccurenceColumnNumber) {
        this.firstOccurenceColumnNumber = firstOccurenceColumnNumber;
    }
}
```

Now I can create my searchWord method. I give him the word to look for, the fileName and a WordInfo object to fill as input parameters

```
public static boolean searchWord(String word, String filePath, WordInfo wInfo) throws IOException {

    boolean result = false;
    boolean firstOccurenceFound = false;
    int lineNumber = 0;

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(filePath)));
    String line = null;

    while ( (line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

        lineNumber++;

        numberOfLineOccurences= 0;

        if (line.indexOf(word) != -1) {
            if (!result) {
                result = true;
            }
            if (!firstOccurenceFound) {
                firstOccurenceFound = true;
                wInfo.setFirstOccurenceLineNumber(lineNumber);
                wInfo.setFirstOccurenceColumnNumber(line.indexOf(word) + 1);


            }
            wInfo.upOccurrence(countNumberOfTimesInALine(line, word));
        }


    }

    reader.close();

    return result;
}
```

Here is an illustration and the result below

I have the following content in a file called DemoFile.txt

[image: data example for test here]

And I test the code using the following main method (I am looking for the word `concept`for example):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    WordInfo wInfo = new WordInfo("concept");
    if ( searchWord("concept", FILE_PATH, wInfo)) {
        System.out.println("Searching for " + wInfo.getWord());
        System.out.println("First line where found : " + wInfo.getFirstOccurenceLineNumber());
        System.out.println("First column found: " + wInfo.getFirstOccurenceColumnNumber());
        System.out.println("Number of occurrences " + wInfo.getNumberOfOccurences());


    }


}
```

And I obtain the following results:

[image]